# vagrant / puphpet : running apache as vagrant user

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, puphpet

I am developing symfony inside of a vagrant box. Recently I tried to boost performance (10k latency) and [found this article](https://beberlei.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html).

It is suggesting to use /dev/shm/ for cache and logs.

This works like a charm, but comes with a problem. Lets say, I create the assets. Then the created files belong to the wrong user, because I am logged in as a vagrant user.

```
[05:33 ]-[vagrant@machine1]-[/var/www/backend]-[git dippingbird/master]
$ ls -lsah /dev/shm/appname/
total 0
0 drwxrwxr-x 4 vagrant vagrant 80 Mar 21 05:28 ./
0 drwxrwxrwt 3 root    root    80 Mar 21 05:28 ../
0 drwxrwxr-x 3 vagrant vagrant 60 Mar 21 05:28 cache/
0 drwxrwxr-x 2 vagrant vagrant 60 Mar 21 05:29 logs/
```

When I want to visit the page in dev environment, it clearly does not work. It says in the browser:

[image: Failed to write cache file "/dev/shm/appname/cache/dev/classes.php]

If I change the permissions to -R 777 it clearly works.

So I figured out, that I want apache run as the vagrant user. But internet documentation is vague. I want to do it via my puphpet config.yaml so it is available for all developers in the team.

Or do I have a braintwist? Why is this permission error not occuring when I am using the `dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';` for logs / cache.